# Create nested array of object upto a limit

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, nested, lodash

> ```
> I have an array of objects like this
> ```

```
    const ticketsData = [
            { id: 1, title: 'parent', parent: 0, url: '' },
            { id: 2, title: 'parent', parent: 0, url: '' },
            { id: 3, title: 'child', parent: 1, url: '' },
            { id: 4, title: 'sub child', parent: 3, url: '' },
            { id: 5, title: 'sub sub child', parent: 4, url: '' },
            { id: 6, title: 'sub sub sub child', parent: 5, url: '' },
            { id: 10, title: 'sub sub child 2', parent: 4, url: '' },
            { id: 13, title: 'sub child 2', parent: 3, url: '' },
            { id: 14, title: 'child', parent: 2, url: '' },
            { id: 7, title: 'sub sub sub child', parent: 5, url: '' },
            { id: 8, title: 'sub sub sub child', parent: 5, url: '' },
            { id: 9, title: 'sub sub sub child', parent: 5, url: '' },
            { id: 11, title: 'sub sub child 3', parent: 4, url: '' },
            { id: 12, title: 'sub sub child 4', parent: 4, url: '' }
          ];
```

> and I want to create a nested array of object upto a limit, say 10. So when the count reduces to zero it should return the array till that child/parent.

```
> This is my expected Output:

    [{ id: 1, title: 'parent', parent: 0, url: '', children: [
{ id: 3, title: 'child', parent: 1, url: '', children:[
{ id: 4, title: 'sub child', parent: 3, url: '', children:[
{ id: 5, title: 'sub sub child', parent: 4, url: '' , children:[
{ id: 6, title: 'sub sub sub child', parent: 5, url: '', children:[] },
{ id: 7, title: 'sub sub sub child', parent: 5, url: '', children:[] },
{ id: 8, title: 'sub sub sub child', parent: 5, url: '', children:[] },
{ id: 9, title: 'sub sub sub child', parent: 5, url: '', children:[] }
]},
{ id: 10, title: 'sub sub child 2', parent: 4, url: '', children:[] },
{ id: 11, title: 'sub sub child 3', parent: 4, url: '', children:[] }
] }
] }
] }]
```

> I tried this but getting all the objects in separate array.

```
     const createTicketTree = (tickets, count) => {
        let ticketObj = {};
        let ticketHierarchy = []
        tickets.map( ticket => {
          ticketObj[ticket.id] = { ...ticket, children: [] };
            if(ticket.parent && count && count--) {
              ticketObj[ticket.parent].children.push(ticketObj[ticket.id]) 
             }
            else { 
            ticketHierarchy.push(ticketObj[ticket.id]) 
            }
        });
        return ticketHierarchy;
    };
```

> This is how I am calling the function to get the nested parent-children relation upto 10.
> Is there any lodash/underscore implementation to acheive this?
> Any help would be appreciated

```
    createTicketTree(ticketsData, 10);
```

Comment: do you have an example of the wanted result?

Comment: share the expected output format

Comment: @NinaScholz: Updated my expected output

Comment: is the array sorted? why not take the first n objects and build a tree from it?

Comment: actually i don't get the point of havin a limit. do you want a full branch of the tree if the parent is in the count or is the limit the depth of wanted nesting parts?

Comment: Thanks Nina, I wanted the result as given by @Nenad. Limit can be anywhere in the nested hierarchy as soon as the count reaches 0.

Comment: @NinaScholz: could you please help how the sorted array would help? Tried sorting on parent but that includes the object with 'id: 2' as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursive approach with `reduce` method and keep count of added elements inside one variable and check if the count is less then 0 to stop adding elements to array.

```js
const ticketsData = [{"id":1,"title":"parent","parent":0,"url":""},{"id":2,"title":"parent","parent":0,"url":""},{"id":3,"title":"child","parent":1,"url":""},{"id":4,"title":"sub child","parent":3,"url":""},{"id":5,"title":"sub sub child","parent":4,"url":""},{"id":6,"title":"sub sub sub child","parent":5,"url":""},{"id":10,"title":"sub sub child 2","parent":4,"url":""},{"id":13,"title":"sub child 2","parent":3,"url":""},{"id":14,"title":"child","parent":2,"url":""},{"id":7,"title":"sub sub sub child","parent":5,"url":""},{"id":8,"title":"sub sub sub child","parent":5,"url":""},{"id":9,"title":"sub sub sub child","parent":5,"url":""},{"id":11,"title":"sub sub child 3","parent":4,"url":""},{"id":12,"title":"sub sub child 4","parent":4,"url":""}]

let count = 10;

function createTicketTree(data, pid = 0) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (e.parent === pid && count > 0) {
      count--
      const o = { ...e }
      const c = createTicketTree(data, e.id);
      if (c.length) o.children = c;
      r.push(o)
    }

    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = createTicketTree(ticketsData);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nenad, this works perfect. Is there a way do to it without recursion due to performance issues?

Comment: I was referring to http://playcode.io/316025/, I will accept this answer though as there is not much difference in performance. Thanks again for saving my day.

Comment: You could add some optimization like this https://jsfiddle.net/qm9yghpe/4/ where the data pool gets smaller and smaller.

Comment: You could also go with plain for loops if the performance is important here https://jsfiddle.net/6ozve92d/1/

Comment: can we use this count variable inside the function? As i have to pass this in my function from my state in react.

Comment: You should then create another function that wraps the recursive function. Count variable should be outside the recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `if` condition is what you're looking for. `count` isn't getting modified or saved anywhere. I would modify the if statement to check for the length of the parent ticket's `children`, compared to the count:

`if(ticket.parent && ticketObj[ticket.parent].children.length < count)`

However, I am confused about what the end result is you're looking for, and how you're counting the nested objects in the `children` list.